# C forked processes keep showing in 'ps -a' output

Tags: c, process, fork

I am trying to understand how fork() works. Here is a piece of code i whipped up:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    while(1){
        if( fork() == 0){
            printf( "%s\n", "this is child process" );
            exit(0);
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

The output is exactly what i would expect ('this is child process' once a second), so I guess all child processes are exiting when I want them to, but whenever i run 'ps -a' while the program is running, i see the list of processes growing at the rate one per second. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not reaping your zombie processes.

Answer (score 1):

The process becomes *zombies* until they are *reaped*. That happens when the parent process calls [`wait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html).

Since the child process exits immediately, you could also call `wait` without it blocking to much:

```
while(1){
    if( fork() == 0){
        printf( "%s\n", "this is child process" );
        exit(0);
    }
    wait(NULL);
    sleep(1);
}
```

---

These zombies exists to hold information that could be passed on the parent process, like for example the child process exit code.

If the parent process exits without reaping its children, the orphaned children becomes children of the `init` process instead, which will reap (`call`wait`) on those.